# Run bash script in k8 container at start

Tags: kubernetes

When running a bash script in a k8 pod, what's the difference between `Command: []string{"sh", "-c", "scripts/start-script.sh"}` and `Command: []string{"sh", "scripts/start-script.sh"}` ? Do they accomplish the same thing? Which one is better?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to mention `sh` at all.

```golang
Command: []string{"scripts/start-script.sh"},
```

This sounds like it might be the normal thing to start the default main process in the container.  If your image's Dockerfile already has this as a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` then you don't need to specify `Command:` in a Pod spec.

The `sh -c` form starts a shell, has that shell interpret the string `scripts/start-script.sh`, and runs that.  This can result in an extra process, and there can be significant security concerns (*shell injection* attacks) if you don't completely control the command string.  If you need to inject environment variables into the command line, use features like redirections or pipelines (maybe a little more likely in a Job spec), or run multiple commands (sequentially) then you would need `sh -c`.

The `sh` form explicitly specifies that you need to use the system Bourne shell to run the script.  If the script isn't a POSIX shell script – it uses features from GNU bash, it's actually in Python – this won't work.

In normal use, the script should be executable, and its first line should be a "shebang" line `#!/bin/sh` or similar.  This tells the system what interpreter to use to execute it.  With that standard setup, you don't need to include the interpreter name in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Hey no they would do not the same. with the command sh you say that you want to run the shell which is an input/output cli tool.

"-c" It is an option for the shell command. It indicates that the subsequent argument should be interpreted as a command or script to be executed by the shell.

If you dont specify -c the shell dont know what to do with your subsequent argument. in your case "scripts/start-script.sh"